# Continue to get duplicate results with SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I was thinking it might be an issue with the joins? I've tried Group by to no avail... 
Any advice would be appreicated! I've placed the query below:

*Sorry for the lack of details- Med_Prof_Record_No is the unique value, and I know the code is messy- but this is what was here when I got here ;-) Also this is a sql 2000 box, so new syntax won't work... I've cleaned up the joins abit but don't want to stray too far from the original queries-

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    P.Last_name + ', ' + P.First_name AS Full_name,   
    P.Degree, 
    F.Med_Prof_Record_No, 
    F.Current_status, 
    F.Status_category, 
    F.Department_name, 
    F.Section, 
    F.SPHAffiliatedPhysiciansSurgeons AS Affiliated,
    S.Board_Name, 
    S.Specialty_Name,
    O.Office_name, 
    O.Address_1, 
    O.Address_2, 
    O.City, 
    O.State, 
    O.Zip_Code, 
    O.Phone_number_1, 
    O.Fax_number
FROM 
    Med_Prof P, Med_Prof_Facilities F, Med_Prof_Specialties S, Med_Prof_Offices O
WHERE         
    (F.Med_Prof_Record_No = P.Med_Prof_Record_No) AND 
    (F.Med_Prof_Record_No = S.Med_Prof_Record_No) AND
    (F.Med_Prof_Record_No = O.Med_Prof_Record_No) AND        
    <cfif URL.LastName is NOT "">(P.Last_name LIKE '#URL.LastName#%') AND</cfif>
    <cfif URL.Specialty is NOT "">(F.Section = '#URL.Specialty#') AND</cfif>
    <cfif URL.Group is NOT "">(O.Office_name LIKE '#URL.Group#%') AND</cfif>                
    (F.Status_category = 'active')
ORDER by Full_name
```

Comment: Not understanding what is the problem. This query returns duplicates?

Comment: Might need some more info here. Your schema, example of duplicate result and desired result.

Comment: If you have a single person (from `P`) that belongs to more than one facility, or has more than one specialty, or is associated with more than one office, you're going to get multiple rows *by definition*. Adding `DISTINCT` doesn't help SQL Server determine which row you want when there are multiple rows with different values in certain columns, since `DISTINCT` applies to ALL columns. You'll need to provide much better information - for example, if a person belongs to two facilities, which one do you want to show? If you only want one per person, you need to tell SQL Server how to pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a stab. This makes assumptions about how you want to decide which office etc. to show (in this case it is as good as arbitrary), that `P.Med_Prof_Record_No` is unique and only represents one person (at first I thought `Last_name` + `First_name` is unique, but that seems a very dangerous assumption), and also that you are using SQL Server 2005 or better. Finally, [please use properly qualified object names](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [please, please, please stop using lazy implicit joins of the `FROM foo, bar, blat, splunge` variety](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT 
    P.Last_name + ', ' + P.First_name AS Full_name,   
    P.Degree, 
    F.Med_Prof_Record_No, 
    -- other columns from F,
    S.Board_Name, 
    S.Specialty_Name,
    O.Office_name,
    -- other columns from O,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.Med_Prof_Record_No
      ORDER BY F.Current_status, S.Board_name, O.Office_name)
  FROM 
    dbo.Med_Prof AS P
  INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Med_Prof_Facilities AS F
    ON P.Med_Prof_Record_No = F.Med_Prof_Record_No
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Med_Prof_Specialties AS S
    ON F.Med_Prof_Record_No = S.Med_Prof_Record_No
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Med_Prof_Offices AS O
    ON F.Med_Prof_Record_No = O.Med_Prof_Record_No
  WHERE         
    <cfif ... AND</cfif>
    -- other <cfif> clauses
    (F.Status_category = 'active')
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Full_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review- you are correct that Med_Prof_Record_No is the unique value, and I think this is a great approach to the problem (using the sub-query/with clause). Unfortunately it is a SQL 2000 box, and the database itself has no documentation, so I was working with some pre-existing (eg.2002-03?) code which I was worried of editing.

Comment: @JasonC In 2000 this is going to be a much more complex query; window functions were added in SQL Server 2005. If you provide actual requirements there may be a chance to help you. As an aside, if you're using a 13-year old platform that is long beyond mainstream support, please indicate that in your question from the start - saves people spending time writing up a solution that can't possibly help you.